# Implementing a reply-by-email comment system that integrates with subscriptions

Tags: 7, notifications

I'm trying to implement a reply-by-email flow on an existing site that will allow users to reply to comments made on the site directly from the email sent informing them of a new comment.

The site (Drupal 7) is using the subscriptions module and has some custom functionality built around that module based on requirements for that site.

I attempted to use the mailcomment module with the notifications module but there is a lot of functionality conflicts and overlaps with the subscriptions module and notifications. I would just remove the subscriptions module and use the notifications module but the site is too intertwined with subscriptions.

Does anyone know of a reply-by-email solution that integrates well with subscriptions? Or, have any ideas/alternatives for doing a reply-by-email system in Drupal 7?